# Caps Lock Toggle in Batch File?

Tags: windows, batch-file, capslock

I am writing a batch file program which utilises the **choice** command like so:

`choice /C Xx /N /CS`

Don't fret about the /M switch, or the /T and /D switch pair, I just want to fool-proof this program so that a user can not accidentally, due to being unaware of the Caps Lock state, make the wrong choice. I have read numerous articles, on the Microsoft site, here at SO, and other external internet sources, that provide batch file solutions, but all of these solutions have involved some sort of external program, like a VBS script or the like. I don't mind being referred to an external source, or another question on SO if it meets my needs.

In short, I would like to be able to toggle Caps Lock in **pure batch**, without using **anything** except batch file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you remove the `/CS` option, the choice will be case-insensitive and you don't need to worry about the state of caps lock.

Comment: @SomethingDark Please read comment on answer (so you don't think I'm a stupid noob :P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't - Windows BAT/CMD script language does not have a way to do so. Complete list of statements/command directly supported by CMD is available on [TechNet:CMD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490880.aspx). Note that even `choice` you are using is not part of the script language itself.

As pointed in comments removing "/CS" option will do case insensitive comparison you are looking for:

> choice /?
>      ...
>      /CS                 Enables case-sensitive choices to be selected. By default, the utility is case-insensitive.

Unless you are targeting very old (I think 3.1 or maybe vanilla 95) version of Windows you can safely use VBS as it is always present on more recent versions as well as JavaScript. If you are looking for additional command line utilities check out [XP command line reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx) as it will give you most broadly available list of tools.

Comment: I did not think it was possible, but I had to ask to be sure. And I realise that it seems I am incredibly 'nooby' to have /CS enabled, but I must use it for user ease. The 'x' choice executes a certain command set, and the 'X' choice adds on to this certain command set before executing it. The capital is used because it is easy to remember - typing x, or shift+x. And before you ask, there are 23 other commands in my program, so using 'y' or the like to substitute for the 'shift+x' is impractical.

Comment: If you're seriously making the user pick from 23+ choices in a single menu, I'd recommend looking into UI design tutorials. There are several schools of thought about how many options is "best" for a menu selection, but none of them suggest more than 10.